# Can webpack replace requirejs, commonjs?

Tags: webpack, requirejs, commonjs

I'm new to front-end world.
As my question above, can webpack do all the thing of requirejs and commonjs?

I also see that ES6 has a feature: `Modules in ES6`

It seems like these things are most the same.

Please help to illuminate my mind. Thank you

Comment: It depends on the needs of the project.  For some projects the answer is "yes". For other projects the answer is "no" because they do things that Webpack cannot handle.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Can be, webpack more powerful than gulp, grunt, support ES6 and can be converted to ES5, because of its babel module; also supports commonJS, AMD, requireJS, etc.

Answer (score -2):

Yes it can, WebPack is a module loader, you can use require statement (es6 standard) to load on demand.

In a previous project we used angular 2 + webpack to do the whole UI process